# Why this mysql query is executing twice or sometimes thrice?

Tags: php, mysql

My code checks if a unique visitor id exists. If it doesn't exists then it assigns a cookie with a unique id. It then checks if session exists. If it doesn't exists then it inserts a record in table as the visitor's visit with time stamp.

The following code is in **root.php**

```
<?php

//Start Session
@session_start();
//Start Session

//Database Credentials
$a = 'localhost'; //Server Name
$b = "root"; //Database Username
$c = ""; //Database Password
$d = 'database_name'; //Database Name
//Database Credentials

//Connection To Database
$conn = mysqli_connect($a, $b, $c, $d);
if($conn->connect_error)
{
    die(); //Connection To Database Failed
}
//Connection To Database

//Cookies
$cookie_1 = "visitor_id";
//Cookies

//Status
$status_0 = 0;
$status_1 = 1;
$status_2 = 2;
//Status

//India's Current Date Time
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$time = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
//India's Current Date Time

//Session
if(isset($_SESSION['session']))
{
    //Expire The Session If User Is Inactive For A Period Of Time
    $last_action = $_SESSION['last_action'];
    $seconds_inactive = time() - $last_action;

    $expire_after = 10 * 60; //10 Minutes

    if($seconds_inactive >= $expire_after)
    {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }
    //Expire The Session If User Is Inactive For A Period Of Time

    //Visitor ID
    $visitor_id = $_SESSION['visitor_id'];
    @setcookie($cookie_1, $visitor_id, time() + (86400 * 365), "/", "", FALSE, TRUE);
    //Visitor ID
}
elseif(!isset($_SESSION['session']))
{
    //Mark The Session Active
    $_SESSION['session'] = 1;
    //Mark The Session Active

    //Visitor ID
    if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_1]))
    {
        $visitor_id = $_COOKIE[$cookie_1];
        @setcookie($cookie_1, $visitor_id, time() + (86400 * 365), "/", "", FALSE, TRUE);
    }
    elseif(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_1]))
    {
        $visitor_id = uniqid("", TRUE); //Assign An Unique ID
        @setcookie($cookie_1, $visitor_id, time() + (86400 * 365), "/", "", FALSE, TRUE);
    }

    $_SESSION['visitor_id'] = $visitor_id;
    //Visitor ID

    //Record The Visit  
    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO visits (visitor_id, visit_time, visit_status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $query->bind_param("ssi", $visitor_id, $time, $status_1);

    $query->execute();
    //Record The Visit
}
//Session

?>
```

This file is included in my **index.php file** like this

```
<?php require_once('root.php'); ?>
```

Now when the index page is loaded the `root.php` executes and I don't know why sometimes it's working correctly, sometimes it inserts more than one record with a difference of 1 second.

Mostly the problem is occurring after the browser history is cleared.

Comment: Don't refresh the page again, because the old query is executed each time when you refresh the page, what's why the is no validation. try to click on the URL and hit the enter button then you'll never!

Comment: Remove the `@` characters before the `session_start();` and `setcookie();` calls, they are not helping.

Comment: if you have a blank line before the "<?php" then the session may not work.  it must be the very first thing in index.php and root.php